# How to send a List of Object on Insomnia or Postman with multipart/form-data structure

Tags: list, arraylist, postman, form-data, insomnia

I have a fromForm **List object** on my Post method like this:

`[FromForm]List<ObjectDTO> ObjectDto`

and I can't test on Insomnia (UI) nor Postman (UI) because I have no idea how to pass a list of objects. I have tried many ways but didn't work, Like:

`ObjectDto = [{param1: 0, param2: 0},{param1: 1, param2: 1}]`

`ObjectDto = [{"param1": 0,"param2": 0},{param1: 1, "param2": 1}]`

`ObjectDto = [{"param1"= 0,"param2"= 0},{param1: 1, "param2"= 1}]`

`ObjectDto[0] = {"param1": 0, "param2": 0}`

When testing the fromForm without being a list, just the object, it works fine on Insomnia with:

`ObjectDto.param1 = 1`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZNpZ.png)

Please, someone help me!

Answer (score -1):

Based on your data structure you maybe better suited to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`

`multipart/formdata` is best used for files but can also be used for a mixture of files and string inputs, here's some examples.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp
(use try it yourself to see how the `multipart/formdata` body will be sent)

how it would be done in insomnia: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9qpx.jpg